# How to control a Sonoff Basic switch with an Arduino Nano

Tags: arduino, switches, opto-isolator

My goal is to "switch" a Sonoff Basic (board RF R2 Power) from an Arduino Nano (which is connected to a few sensors). Based on this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qTOkpNAWMe8), I found which pin to use on the Sonoff. After a test, this is working by connecting **KEY** and **GND** very briefly. I used the white cable you can see on this picture. It is always +3.3 V (from `KEY`) but when you shorten **KEY** to **GROUND** for a sec it switches on release.

[image: Sonoff Basic (board RF R2 Power)]

Now, I am working on how to "replace" the white cable with the Arduino it-self. I used the following diagram with R1 = 50Ω.

[image: diagram]

Question:

- How can I calculate value for R1 because 50 is a guess from what I found over the web.

Problem:

- The Sonoff Basic does **NOT** start if it boots after the Arduino. No green LED. It works fine if the Sonoff boots first, then the Arduino right after.

Any idea what is the cause and how to solve this ?

This is the code I use on the Arduino Nano to test the whole thing. Basically it changes de Sonoff switch position every 4 seconds.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT); //Pin 3 triggers camera via optop-isolator
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
}

void loop() {
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(3, LOW);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Do you have a schematic of the key circuit as used on the board or maybe a data sheet that explains what ought to be done rather than guessing.

Comment: If i understand correctly from this [web site](https://www.electroschematics.com/sonoff-basic-wi-fi-switch/) the breakout I am trying to "hack" should be used with a RF module which is not included on my model.

Comment: Pretty sure you need to use an *output* on the Nano and swap sides on your opto-isolator, otherwise what it looks like you are trying to do is use the `Key` to drive an input on the Nano. As your question asks, it's the other way around...

Comment: Thanks Ron, I just realized my error. I fixed my post. How can I confirm it can work with Opto and not a relay ? Thanks

Comment: I updated the question with my actual wiring and the new boot order problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been solved by adding a **PULL DOWN** resistor to ensure default state **LOW** on the Arduino side (add a 10k resistor from PIN 1 to GND).

I used this [article](https://circuitdigest.com/tutorial/pull-up-and-pull-down-resistor) to understand.